# Open content of Tabitem in new Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

What i want to do is open a new window exactly the same as my TabItem. I tried this:

```
Window wnd = new Window();
var cnt = tabItem1.Content;
wnd.Content = cnt;
wnd.Show();
```

After button click it open nice new window with tab control content, but content in my main window disappear. When I switch to another tab item in my main window and again to TabItem1 everything is ok in  main window, but "new window" is empty then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that code. Each WPF control can't have more than one parent in the logical (or visual) tree. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391(v=vs.110).aspx).
You should use a template in order to have the same content both in your Tab Control and in your Window.